# phptidy textarea with HTML formated text

Tags: php, html, textarea

i am using a Javascript to produce a HTML encoded textarea, this works ok i then store into the SQL database. this is ok. but when i want to output this back into the textarea to be edited again php-tidy moves the closing textarea tags to before the content so actually putting the content after the textarea tags. this only happens when the content is formated with HTML tags but these are required to produce the formatting i need to produce HTML formated emails etc. when i disable PHP-tidy all works ok just the HTML code is a complete mess

If anyone has anyway to get PHP-tidy to ignore some parts of code or exempt textarea from being parsed by PHP-tidy that would be great.

the code i have is simple

//content from database

```
$message = stripslashes($database['message']);
$buffer = "<textarea id=\"elm1\" name=\"message\" cols=\"70\" rows=\"20\">$message</textarea>";

$config = array('indent' => TRUE,
           'doctype' => "strict",
            'output-xhtml' => TRUE,
            'wrap' => 300);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($buffer, $config);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```

if the message has no HTML content the formatting is ok

php tidy disabled it come out like, yes formatting not so good but works how I expect

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="Message" cols="70" rows="20"><p>this is a full html email.</p>
<p>little formatting </p>
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">different colour text</span></p>
<p>and normal</p></textarea>
```

php tidy enabled

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="Message" cols="70" rows="20">
</textarea>
    <p>
      this is a full html email.
    </p>
    <p>
      little formatting
    </p>
    <p>

      <span style="color: #ff0000;">different colour text</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      and normal
    </p>
```

I would like PHP-tidy enabled but still have the outcome I expect

Thanks

Vip32

Comment: No way to help without you code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = stripslashes($database['message']);
// DO the tidy before interpolating with
// the html of your form element
$config = array('indent' => TRUE,
           'doctype' => "strict",
            'output-xhtml' => TRUE,
            'wrap' => 300);

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($message, $config);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// now insert it into the correct place

$buffer = "<textarea id=\"elm1\" name=\"message\" cols=\"70\" rows=\"20\">$tidy</textarea>";

echo $buffer;
```

You were just assembling things in the wrong order I think.

**untested**